# Multithread Client Socket has CPU 100% in JAVA

Tags: java, json, multithreading, sockets, client

I have a serious problem. Actually I have a Client program which receive approximately 2000 JSON strings per second from a Server (Data rate of receive data is very high). I have to connect to server with several Ports which every port must handles with a Thread. On the other side, I have to get the data with Read() function char by char, because it is not clear at all how it is sent from server (ReadLine and ReadUTF sometimes don't work because server get data from some Real Sensors and they are unpredictable).

The main problem is When I run the program, the program begins to receive data at high speeds. But CPU goes to 100% in Java Run time and the speed of get data goes to slow after 30 second.
the source code is here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client implements Runnable{

private Socket clientSocket = null;
private BufferedReader is = null;
private int port;

public Client(int port){
    this.port = port;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



    Client a = new Client(7002);
    Thread one = new Thread(a);

    Client b = new Client(7003);
    Thread two = new Thread(b);
    Client c = new Client(7004);
    Thread three = new Thread(c);



    one.start();
    two.start();  
    three.start();

}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("hi from thread" + port);
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.156", port);
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    } 
    catch( IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try{ 
     //***************************************Port 7002*****************************************            
        while(port == 7002){
            String str = "";
            StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            while (is.ready()) {                    
                char[] c = new char[]{1};
                is.read(c);
                sbuffer.append(c);
                if (c[0]=='}') 
                {
                    str = sbuffer.toString();
                    if ((str.charAt(0)=='{')&(str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='}')) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received data from port 7002: "+str);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Received Data Lost!!!!");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
       //***************************************Port 7003*****************************************            
        while(port == 7003){
            String str = "";
            StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            while (is.ready()) {                    
                char[] c = new char[]{1};
                is.read(c);
                sbuffer.append(c);
                if (c[0]=='}') 
                {
                    str = sbuffer.toString();
                    if ((str.charAt(0)=='{')&(str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='}')) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received data from port 7003: "+str);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Received Data Lost!!!!");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
       //***************************************Port 7004*****************************************            
        while(port == 7004){
            String str = "";
            StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            while (is.ready()) {                    
                char[] c = new char[]{1};
                is.read(c);
                sbuffer.append(c);
                if (c[0]=='}') 
                {
                    str = sbuffer.toString();
                    if ((str.charAt(0)=='{')&(str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='}')) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received data from port 7004: "+str);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Received Data Lost!!!!");
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

Please Help me to solve the problem.

Comment: How many threads running? How many cores on CPU(s)? Are all cores hitting 100% usage?

Comment: just 3 threads running and all cores hitting 100%. My CPU is Core i7 8 generation

Comment: And how many real cores, and is hyper-threading engaged? Before posting, think through all the details necessary for an appropriate Answer.

Comment: Just 4 real cores. I think the problem is the main source code. is it possible to change it to better the source code to consume lower CPU usage?

Comment: First, do **not** use StringBuffer. You can do directly `new String(c)`. Then, re-use the same char[], do not recreate it at each loop. Also, you should check again your if condition. But, most importantly, read does not ensure to fully fill the char arrray. It will return a number of read bytes, that you must use to adapt your algorithm.

Comment: For the last point, it's really important to "block" i.e putting your thread to wait if input reader does not deliver enough data at the time, so you're not constantly looping (that is what cause the heavy CPU load here I *think*). Anyway, for such task, you should consider using well-tested solutions, like *reactor-netty*.

Comment: You're char buffer is actually only **one** character in size, not 1024. That won't help throughput.